# Prestashop: Call to undefined function mysql_connect

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I installed prestashop using softaculous, my php version is 5.2.17 and despite of that it shows this

> ERROR: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/adeego/public_html/prestashop/classes/db/MySQL.php on line 51

If I go changing php version then it will be very painful to change every `mysql_` into `mysqli_` or `pdo_mysqli_`.

What is the best solution?

Comment: if you're really running PHP 5.2.17 the mysql_connect function should still be available. It was removed in PHP 7

Comment: Is the MySQL Extension loaded?

Comment: everything is loaded.

Comment: it says like this: PHP Extension 20060613